# AWS CloudFormation init services as bash script

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I would like to know what's the bash equivalent for below CloudFormation code.

```
ServerLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          install_all:
            - install_cfn
        install_cfn: 
          ..some important staff..
          services:
            sysvinit:
              cfn-hup:
                enabled: 'true'
                ensureRunning: 'true'
                files:
                  - /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf
                  - /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf
```

I want **services** part to be done by bash script because at the time it's executed, files */etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf* and */etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf* does not exist. I'm creating them as part of **UserData**. I'm aware that they can, and probably should be created by **files** in Init.

When I run command:

```
systemctl status cfn-hup.service
```

I get:

> Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cfn-hup; bad; vendor preset:
>   disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code)

This is predictable as those files does not exist while trying. But I can actually start this service later with success using `service cfn-hup start`.

**Question**:

Will results be the same when I leave those **services** as they are and then after crating .conf files I will call: `service cfn-hup start`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, [Configsets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) can solve this problem for you.

> Configsets If you want to create more than one config key and to have
>   cfn-init process them in a specific order, create a configset that
>   contains the config keys in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not sure if u get my question right. I'm already using configSets, but it's not the case. I want to know how to do CloudFormation `service` by only using bash.